# How to use Android Action Bar Style Generator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

In the current version of eclipse, drawable folder is not there. Where do i put those xml sheets? I followed the tutorial on youtube but its not working on my system.

Comment: if not there than you can create rec->drawable and put it :)

Answer (score 0):

The xml sheets generated by the Action Bar Style Generator go into the styles.xml file. The images generated go into a the drawable-xxxx folder which you can create yourself in res.

Comment: ab_background_textured_theme1, btn_cab_done_theme1, progress_horizontal_theme1, selectable_background_theme1, spinner_background_ab_theme1, tab_indicator_ab_theme1 are the xml files in the drawable folder. So i copy paste the contents in the style.xml file? what about the style.xml file in values-v11 and values-v14? Do i have to change them too?